# How to bind a child user control's data context in the parent

Tags: wpf, xaml

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ChildGroupName, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True,Mode=TwoWay}"
TargetUpdated="OnTextUpdated"/>
```

Here `ChildGroupName` is a child control datacontext property. I want to bind `ChildGroupName` values to parent window.

Comment: Share more code which will help understand the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `FindAncestor` to data bind to a descendant's data... the clue is in its name. If the child `UserControl` is defined in the same XAML as the parent, then you can provide it with a name and then use the [`Binding.ElementName` Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.elementname(v=vs.110).aspx) to data bind to its properties:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ChildPropertyName, ElementName=NameOfChildUserControl, 
    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, Mode=TwoWay}" 
    TargetUpdated="OnTextUpdated" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Sheridan's answer did not work for me, because ReSharper was issuing a warning saying that "ChildPropertyName" is an unknown property.

Now, I did not actually try Sheridan's solution; it may be that it would have worked; it may be that WPF does smart tricks under the hood and manages to get things to work even with Sheridan's approach; however, for me, all warnings must always be enabled, and all code must be absolutely free from warnings, so I had to look for a solution that would not only work, but also work without eliciting a warning from ReSharper.

What worked for me was adding `DataContext.`, as follows (without the extra clutter):

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding DataContext.ChildPropertyName,
    ElementName=NameOfChildUserControl}" />
```

In other words, when you use `ElementName`, the `DataContext` becomes the element itself, (which makes sense,) so in order to get to the actual viewmodel you need to first reference the `DataContext` of the element.